# How to get the server host and port of a started express app in a utility file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've a need to know the server host name and port on which the express app in another javascript file say under lib. How can I get it?

I tried to do module.exports = app but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring an express app, you can export a listener which will give you the host and address:

**/index.js**

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world!\n');
});

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

module.exports = listener;
```

Then you can `require` that module in your lib files to be able to access the host and port:

**/lib/index.js**

```
var listener = require('./../index.js');
var address = listener.address();
var host = address.address;
var port = address.port;
console.log('Listening on ' + host + ':' + port);
// < - 'Listening on :::3000'
```